# android:layout_below= does not place item below

Tags: xml, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android

I have an editText and a textView which I'm attempting to set below an imageView however the parameter  android:layout_below= does not place item below.

How might this be avoided?

Also I'm setting      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" on the textView, editText and imageView and that does not seem to be working either.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.project.DragLayer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="@color/grid_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
                android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dip" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1.0" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="onClickAddImage"
                    android:text="Add image" />

                <com.example.project.DeleteZone
                    android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete_zone" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/sqwhite"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/sqwhite"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.project.DragLayer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Linear Layout, if you switch to Relative Layout, `android:layout_below` will work.

`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` will work for Relative Layout too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it (updated source above) but it still looks the same : (

Comment: @Droidzilla you could try removing the plus sign. Like:  *android:layout_below="@id/sqwhite"*. Once it's already created, you don't need '+'.

Comment: @Droidzilla You should remove android:orientation="vertical" from your Relative Layout too, it only works for Linear Layout.

Comment: I tried it (updated source above) but it still looks the same : (

Comment: I have a link to the full package source if that helps at all... 

http://www.sendspace.com/file/bom4fw

Comment: Any ideas? It still appears the same

Comment: @Droidzilla did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` inside the following `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
    ...
    >

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it (updated source above) but it still looks the same : (

Comment: Change android:layout_below="@+id/sqwhite" to android:layout_below="@id/sqwhite" in your EditText and also android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" to android:layout_below="@id/editText1" in TextView as sqwhite and editText1 are already defined above.

Comment: I tried it (updated source above) but it still looks the same : (

Comment: I have a link to the full package source if that helps at all... 

http://www.sendspace.com/file/bom4fw

Answer (score 0):

you code perfectly working fine. issue is height and width of image. try below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.project.DragLayer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@color/grid_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
            android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dip" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_part"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_add_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:onClick="onClickAddImage"
                android:text="Add image" />

            <com.example.project.DeleteZone
                android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_zone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sqwhite"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="#657654"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sqwhite"
                        android:background="#843577"  
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#454544"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just tried this... the editText still appears above the textView - not below it : (

Answer (score 0):

You are treating your RelativeLayout (the one with the button, DeleteZone, and FrameLayout) like a LinearLayout. For these three children, you need to specify where they are relative to each other or the parent. Parameters like `layout_weight` and `layout_gravity` are meaningless to a View that is the child of a RelativeLayout. By default, they will all be jammed in the upper left corner of the RelativeLayout, since you are not specifying where they go.

Personally, I would remove both LinearLayouts, both RelativeLayouts, and the FrameLayout, and use a single RelativeLayout for all of the children. That would be much cleaner.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I just tried this... and it isn't working like I hoped: http://pastebin.com/v2VXc6e5

Comment: It's actually force closing on me after that change... 

http://pastebin.com/GmZcj1Pb

Comment: The crash has something to do with the library you're using. Might be an Eclipse error. Try turning off "Build automatically" in the Project menu and see if that fixes it. Or in the project properties, in Java Build Path -> Order and Export, make sure your library is checked.

I don't know what you want the correct layout to look like so I can't really suggest a specific layout. Can you post a picture?